# run editor command when leaving insert mode in vim

Tags: vim, editors

I want to run a `:command` in vim when I exit insert mode. Specifically I want to run `:GoFmt` to format my code when I exit insert mode. Currently it runs when I save the file but sometimes I want to format before I do a syntax check (which happens when I save the file).

My current solution was to map `<esc>` to `<esc>:GoFmt<enter>` but this breaks the behavior of the arrow keys because the arrow keys start with an escape sequence. Is there a better solution?

```
autocmd FileType go imap <esc> <esc>:GoFmt<enter>
```

Comment: You might get a more in-depth answer to this over at the vi/Vim stack exchange, just FYI.  http://vi.stackexchange.com  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well first, I strongly support Wildcards suggestion to go to the [vim site...](http://vi.stackexchange.com) :)

But second, there is definitely a better solution. You can use an `InsertLeave` autocommand. Just do this:

```
autocommand InsertLeave go GoFmt
```

The advantage is that this doesn't require any mappings at all, and running the command is also simpler because `GoFmt` is already an ex command, so you do not need the `:...<cr>`.